# Define a function with a function handler as argument

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Is it possible to define a function with a function handler as an argument in Matlab?

I've tried with

```
function x = name(@f,gh)
```

but I get an error message stating Invalid syntax at '@'.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use syntax involving `@` in function definition. The anonymous function handle would do the work:

```
function x = SO_Example(h,gh)
x = h(gh);
```

And you can call the function as follows:

```
SO_Example(@(a)a.^2 , 2)
ans = 4
```

Or like this:

```
h = @(a)a.^2;
SO_Example(h,2)

ans = 4
```

Please, see comments for additional explanations

Comment: To clarify, you might add the explanation that the argument parser will try to parse "@()..something" rather than pass a function handle to the function body.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft good point for understanding of mechanisms behind Matlab. But, aside from this, what is the point in passing `@(...)`? Argument is something that is not known exactly prior to the function execution. I think that OP just wanted to tell Matlab that one of arguments is a function.